# Header issue in MasterDetail page of Xamarin forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I'm using MasterDetail page in my Xamarin.Forms app for UWP.

When i click on menu icon and then navigate to other page from that menu, an extra header appear on that page. But while menu is open, that header goes away like below.

When navigate from menu, page looks like this:

[image: This image is with heder and the issue is marked as red rectangle]

But while menu open, header disappearing:

[image: This image is without Header.]

Hope for better solution

Comment: Hi, could you share related code about the click event of menu item? It will be helpful to check the problem.

Comment: yes just doing IsPresented = true on menu item's click event

Comment: Okey, do you mean the top black toolbar with some menu items inside it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycANX.png

Comment: no not that,  see red highlighted area in first pic. That's extra space appearing when navigating one page to another.

Comment: Okey, you could share code of the navigation, I will check that.